# Como posso fazer uma validação para verificar se uma variável está vazia e é uma string no php

Tags: php, variáveis

Quero fazer uma verificação de negação e depois no `else` o acerto. Como posso fazer?

Vejam o exemplo!

```
<?php

$a = '';


if(!$a && !is_string($a)):
   echo 'False';
else:
   echo 'True';
endif;
```

Comment: Saulo, para verificar se a váriavel esta vazia use a função `empty()` e para verificar se ela é uma string use `ìs_string()` ambos retornos são booleanos.

Comment: Se fizeres a verificação `$a == ''` não te chega para saber se está vazia e ser string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Saulo, você pode também criar uma função

```
<?php

function emptyAndString(&$var)
{
    $var = trim($var);
    return empty($var) && is_string($var);
}

$v = 'Valor';
var_dump(emptyAndString($v));
// bool(false) 

$v = '  ';
var_dump(emptyAndString($v));
// bool(false) 

$v = '';
var_dump(emptyAndString($v));
// bool(true)
```

Comment: Valeu muito Obrigado, resolvido!

Answer (score 4):

Pra deixar mais uma opção, a maneira mais simples de fazer isso é assim:

```
if ($string === '') {
}
```

Com o trim, para garantir que não vai ir nada vazio:

```
if (trim($string) === '') {
}
```

O operador `===` verifica se o valor é identico, ou seja, compara não só os valores, mas os tipos.